# Error exception when show the progress dialog in the async task

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am currently work on an async task to post some data to the API , the problem is it will throw an exception when I was working with the progress dialog. The async task is named "APIhandler" that will handle several type of case.

Here is the constructor

```
   public APIHandler(Context _ctx,EasyTracker _tracker,String _formType) {
        this.ctx = _ctx;
        this.tracker = _tracker;
        this.formType = _formType;

        SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0);
        token = prefs.getString("token","");
        memId = prefs.getString("memId","");

        if (formType.equals("uploadImg")) {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.sys_info),ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.publishing));
        } else {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.sys_info),ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        }
    }
```

Here is the onpostexecute

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        if (pd != null && pd.isShowing())
            pd.dismiss();
}
```

Here is the way to call APIhandler

```
new APIHandler(ctx,tracker,"login").execute(ctx,session.getAccessToken());
```

The error code (notice that it is fail at the dialog.show)

```
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440): Activity com.project.hkseven.Activity.SharePicForm has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4231c268 that was originally added here
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.project.hkseven.Activity.SharePicForm has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4231c268 that was originally added here
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:439)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:307)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:228)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:153)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:586)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at com.project.hkseven.Utility.APIHandler.<init>(APIHandler.java:62)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at com.project.hkseven.Activity.SharePicForm$4.onCompleted(SharePicForm.java:282)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1669)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4882)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-18 14:17:17.942: E/WindowManager(440):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How to fix the problem ? Thanks a lot

Comment: m sorry to say but the log you have posted is because of some other exception that might have taken place. please read the entire log before the window leak error, m sure you will get to the actual error

Comment: Are you finishing the activity SharePicForm after showing the dialog?

Comment: There should be a listener in SharePicForm , that should not closed before the dialog dismiss

Comment: Nope. Its not about listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure that you are not finishing your `SharePicForm` activity before showing dialog. Error shows that your  `SharePicForm` activity does not exist while showing dialog. Or may be it's already exited.